# File Reading for Console

Tags: c++, dev-c++, file-read

Am making a dictionary and have to read various file from various folder of various types! i have found the code for displaying folder in a directory on console! however i dnt understand how to read the txt files inside those folders! and display the file names on the console! Kindly help me with this problem!

Comment: Your question lacks of information. For what operating system is your dictionary application? What is the format (not the extension) of your files? how the data is stored into these files?

Comment: Have you tried google? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think that I might wait! Until you clarify your question and show us your existing code!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to read a text file

```
std::string line;

std::ifstream file ("myfile.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file,line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `file.good()` will return true until *after* the first read has already failed. A better condition is `while (getline(file,line))`, which checks the result of each attempted read.